# Recreating micro speech model from scratch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tflite

Hi I am trying to recreate the micro speech model from looking at the tflite structure.

Here is structure of the tflite
[image: Microspeech tflitemodel structure]

This is me trying recreate the model structure:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers

inputs = layers.Input(shape=(1960,))
x = layers.Reshape(target_shape=(49, 40, 1))(inputs)
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=1, strides=2, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax")(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

Here is the model structure form `model.summary()`

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_42 (InputLayer)       [(None, 1960)]            0         
                                                                 
 reshape_3 (Reshape)         (None, 49, 40, 1)         0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_37 (Conv2D)          (None, 25, 20, 8)         16        
                                                                 
 flatten_6 (Flatten)         (None, 4000)              0         
                                                                 
 dense_67 (Dense)            (None, 4)                 16004     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 16,020
Trainable params: 16,020
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

> I am just wondering whether they used a Flatten layer or not. What should I use instead if so?

Comment: You could also using Global Max Pooling or Global Average Pooling..up to you

Comment: @AloneTogether Possibly, but do you think that is what they did from their model structure?

Comment: Yes, flattening --> 25x20x8 = 4000

Comment: I'm trying to do this too, does anyone know any example tensorflowv2 code for tflite microspeech?